# PHP CURL having 400 while it works

Tags: php, wordpress, php-curl

While checking the URL: [https://i2.wp.com/jarek-kefir.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/pożar-katedry-notre-dame.jpg?ssl=1](https://i2.wp.com/jarek-kefir.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/po%C5%BCar-katedry-notre-dame.jpg?ssl=1)

I have result status code `400`...

This is my function:

```
public function callAPI($url)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    error_log('Checking url: ' . $url);

    // OPTIONS:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        //'APIKEY: 111111111111111111111',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    ));

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    // EXECUTE:

    $result = utf8_decode(curl_exec($curl));
    $result = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $result);

    if (!$result) {
        error_log('Connection Failure ' . $result . ' for url: ' . $url);
    }
    // Check if any error occurred
    $error_msg = '';
    $error_number = curl_errno($curl);
    $error_info = curl_error($curl);

    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    $httpCode = $info['http_code'];
    $request_ok = $httpCode == 200 || $httpCode == 201 || $httpCode == 204;
    error_log('$httpCode: ' . $httpCode);
    if (!$request_ok) {
        $info = curl_error($curl);
        $error_msg = $info ? $info : "Http code: " . $httpCode;
        error_log('Error while checking url: ' . $url . ' : ' . $error_msg);
    }

    curl_close($curl);
    return $error_msg;
}
```

but when I check it manually or even by curl from command line it works fine.
Probably I miss some configuration for curl here..

Comment: Can you add `curl` command for the command line?

Comment: curl -X GET https://i2.wp.com/jarek-kefir.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/pożar-katedry-notre-dame.jpg?ssl=1

Answer (score 1):

heh finally I found out that it is because one polish character.. :)